# ElasticSearch documentation says not to use scroll for user requests, only for data transformation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ES and confused by its documentation of scroll.  From the docs "*Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the contents of of one index into a new index with a different configuration*".

And yet...further down on the same page it says not to use from() and size() to do pagination because it "*is very inefficient*".  And on the Java API page describing Search it shows an example of paging via Scroll.

So, assuming I want to present sorted search results, a page at a time, which approach is recommended: from/size or Scrolling?

Answer (score 8):

`from/size` is very inefficient when you want to do **deep pagination** or if you want to request lots of results by page.

The reason is that results are sorted first on each shard, and all those results are then gathered, merged and sorted by the request coordinator node. This become more and more costly as the pages grow either in size or in rank. You will find a very good example [documented here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html#pagination).

You could limit the size of your users' queries (e.g. to something like ~1000 results), and you will be fine using `from/size`.

If it's not an option, you can still use **scroll**, but you will lose some features like aggregations and [keeping the search context alive has a cost](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context).

Comment: I understand this is an old post. But is losing aggregations in scroll still true?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html mentions aggregations being contained in the initial search response.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `search_after`. The basic process flow will be like this:

1. Perform your regular search to return an array of sorted document results by date.
2. Perform the next query with the `search_after` field in the body to tell Elasticsearch to only return documents after the specified document (date).

This way, your results remain robust against any updates or document deletions and stay accurate. You also avoid the [scrolling costs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api) (as you've likely already read) and the [from/size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) method's linear time operation cost for each query starting from your initial document result.

See the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) for more info and implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Both scroll and from/size suffer from deep pagination. You could try a hybrid approach by doing pagination in larger steps (e.g. 100 entries at a time), but have the UI show in smaller batches (i.e. 10 only). As the user continues to go to the pages, at some point, you should trigger another background search task for the next batch while the user is occupied. If you track these sessions and get a rough idea on how deep users search, you could find your ideal resultset size and scroll in those number of steps.

Between the two, I had better experience with scrolling than from/size in terms of response times, but YMMV. Comes down to your data, shard setup, etc.

Comment: Since v1.2, it seems that scroll perform better in deep pagination that `from/size`, see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan)

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent article about pagination [here](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-pagination-techniques/). The cliff notes seem to be:

- if you're presenting results to a user for **application search: use from/size** (this technique is preferable up to 10,000 results)
- if you're **infinite scrolling, use search_after**- this is more efficient and can be used with > 10,000 results.
- if you have regular inserts on your index, search_after is yet more preferable, because it should avoid duplicates arising from an insert on page 1 pushing results onto page 2.
- if you need users to be able to "go back" (from page 2 to page 1) for example, and see **consistent results**, you need a technique which freezes the results.  This could be either:

  - Point in Time API: ES > 7.10 X-Pack feature
  - Scroll API: Older, free-er versions of ES

The article merits a read if you've got this far.  [Bonus link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-context) to the es pagination docs.